# STDIN seems to be broken after call to "system" invoking mpiexec

Tags: system, stdin, readline, fork, mpiexec

This is my first ever post here, so please excuse any formatting issues.

I have an interactive program which spawns external processes and monitors their IO.  Things work fine until I spawn something off with "mpiexec", after which STDIN appears to break.

I realize this will be difficult to reproduce for most folks, but if anyone sees anything obvious or knows of this problem.... please help!

Here's a snippet:

```
int main( ... )
{
  std::string choice;
  while(std::getline(std::cin,choice)){
     if(!choice.empty()){
       if(choice == "Parallel"){
        system("mpiexec ./aprogram");
       }
       if(choice == "Serial"){
        system("./aprogram");
       }
       // Now the external process is done... so far, so good
       std::cout << "Program is done. Press ENTER to continue." 
                 << std::endl;
       // This next line *works* if the external process was serial
       // But *fails* when "mpiexec" was invoked 
       std::getline(std::cin,choice);
       if(std::cin.eof()){
         std::cout << "STDIN has been closed." << std::endl;
         exit(1);
       }
     }
  }
}
```

I have tried *lots* of various things, e.g. pipes, explicit forking, meticulous descriptor management.  The weirdest thing is that if I dup off and save stdin and then restore it after "mpiexec" returns, then I no longer get EOF on std::cin, but instead, std::getline(std::cin,...) no longer blocks! The program goes into an infinite loop reading zero bytes off std::cin in the std::readline call.

If, while the external process is running under mpiexec, I stack a bunch of data into std::cin (e.g. by typing), then subsequent calls to std::readline correctly parse the lines of data that I have stuck in there, but again... once it is done reading through that data, it just keeps going in an infinite loop (i.e. not blocking on std::readline(std::cin,..) even if there is no data to read!  Ugh.  So annoying.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Which MPI implementation are you using, on which platform?

Comment: We're currently using MPICH-based MPI implementations (several flavors including MVAPICH, vanilla MPICH2, and MPICH-MX) on several different Linux-based platforms (the majority of which are S.L. or CentOS-based). I've not tried with OpenMPI, but some of the apps in this integrated system do not play nice with OpenMPI.  I believe the problem must be centered around something that "mpiexec" is doing with STDIN.  I will try to get a better snippet so that it can be easily reproduced with vanilla mpich.

Comment: I can reproduce your problem with your example code and MPICH-3.0.1.  I'm looking into it.

Comment: Outstanding.  Thanks a lot, Dave.

Comment: No fix yet, but it doesn't appear to actually be closing the underlying file descriptor.  Instead, the `read` call on fd `0` is returning `EAGAIN`, as though stdin has been made nonblocking.  I haven't yet found anywhere we are doing this, but there is definitely something funny happening here.  We'll keep looking at it.

Comment: Thanks, Dave.  I also tried to set the descriptor back to blocking, to no avail.  I'll get back to looking at it again too ... after getting this other junk off my plate.

Comment: I wasn't able to figure out what the problem is in any reasonable amount of time.  I've filed a ticket in our local bug tracker so that we don't forget about the issue: http://trac.mpich.org/projects/mpich/ticket/1782

Answer (score 1):

I think I fixed your problem, for me either a call to Serial or Parallel blocked, and I think it was the std::cin.eof() test,

```
  std::getline(std::cin,choice);
  if(std::cin.eof()){         
     td::cout << "STDIN has been closed." << std::endl;
     exit(1);
   }
```

However, changing this to std::cin.get(), works great for both the parallel run and serial run.

```
   if(std::cin.get()) {
     std::cout << "STDIN has been closed." << std::endl;
     exit(1);
   }
```

Works on my system.